# Chrome ::selection CSS selector fails on textbox

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have written a basic website that calculates SHA1 hashes. I know, there are already hundreds, but this was more to try my hand at designing than making something that a lot of people will use. An important part of my design was displaying the calculated hash in a textbox with the text auto-selected with JavaScript. This textbox has a CSS3 ::-selection pseudo element to change the color of the selected text so it doesn't *look* like a plain 'ol text box. Here is the CSS code:

```
#result::-moz-selection {
    background: white;
    color: red;
}

#result::selection {
    background: white;
    color: red;
}
```

I know I probably could have combined the selectors, but separating them was something I tried when this wasn't working. The HTML is a plain `<input type="text" id="result">`, along with a few other inconsequential attributes. You can see the full code at [SHA1.in](https://sha1.in/). Am I doing something wrong here? TIA!

BTW, I got my code from [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/overriding-the-default-text-selection-color-with-css/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing your `input` element with a `div` seems to fix the issue. Apparently Chrome prevents overriding the selection colors for text `inputs`.

This is a reported bug: [little link](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=62263).

Comment: Good to know, but the reason I use a text box is that users can just press Ctrl+C to copy, since the box is focused and selected once the hash is retrieved. Sucks that it's a bug. Techincally a correct answer, though, so thank you.

Comment: @D.Strout You can select a `div`s text using JavaScript, by the way.

Comment: What about the `contenteditable` attribute? http://html5doctor.com/the-contenteditable-attribute/